# Prove that congruent matrices have the same rank.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone prove that two similar matrices have the same rank?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's your definition of congruency? (Square matrices with same Jordan form? Arbitrary $n \times m$ matrices differing by row operations? ...)

Comment: *[congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence)* or *[similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)*?

Comment: >I'm sorry . 2 matrices ,A en B, are congruent if there is an invertible matrix P so that$ B=P^{T}*A*P$

Comment: Hint: think of a matrix as a linear transformation.

Comment: $rank(P(P^{-1}AP)P^{-1})\le rank(P^{-1}AP)\le rank(A).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are congruent, so $A=S^TBS$. Notice that since $S$ is invertible, so too is $S^T$.Since $S$ is invertible we know that $Im(B)=Im(BS)$.
Hence we also have the rank of $B$ and the rank of $BS$ are the same.Likewise, since $S^T$ is invertible, we know that $Ker(S^T(BS))=Ker(BS)$. Applying the rank nullity theorem and the equality between images , we therefore have 
$rank(A)=rank(S^TBS)=n-dim(Ker(BS))=n-dim(Ker(B))=rank(B)$

Comment: >I still have one question. Can you explain this a bit more please :" Since S is invertible we know that Im(B)=Im(BS)". Thanks

Comment: **Lemma:** Suppose that $C$ and $D$ are matrices. Then $Im(CD)\subseteq Im(C)$ , withequality if $C$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix.

Hint 1: If $G$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, then $A$ and $AG$ have the same column space

Hint 2: If $F$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix, then $A$ and $FA$ have the same rank (because $F$ induces an isomorphism from the column space of $A$ to the column space of $FA$)

Answer (score 3):

Use $\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank}(A)$, and $\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank}(B)$.